# Unable to send email from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I had code to send emails to user when register on our website I did the code but no message was sent and error appeared (failure sending email).

```
bool SendMail(string account, string password, string to, string subject, string message)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(elarabyAccount, password);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(account);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com", 8080);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = loginInfo;
        client.Send(msg);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMail("noreply@example.com", "xxxxx", TxtEmail.Text, "Hi", "Hi");
}
```

Comment: Can you give us additional information about the exception that is caught?

Comment: Have you ever try to [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+smtp)??

Comment: Comment out the try/catch and post the error message that is generated. Also, set post to 25 per Chris's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

you have the port set as 8080. try 25

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect it is simply down to the Port number. For trying to find problems like this in the future though, you should try and see what the error messages you get from a Try - Catch statement

```
try
{
   //code in here
}
catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException exsmtp)
{
    throw new Exception(exsmtp.ToString());
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
}
```

You will get a lot of use(less) information from this :)